# Default optimizer and loss of transformers.Seq2SeqTrainer?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

What is the default optimizer and loss of `transformers.Seq2SeqTrainer`? I checked here https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer but did not see any information.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4520

Answer (score -1):

Default optimiser is AdamW optimiser. You can look into the documentation part of transformers.Seq2SeqTrainingArguments on huggingface. we set parameters required for training in seq2seqTrainingArguments() And then use these in seq2se2Trainer for training.

Comment: Welcome to SO; "*The default is X, you can look into the documentation*" without providing the actual **link** to the relevant documentation does not sound much of an answer, does it? Please edit & update your answer accordingly.